# Sort array fix code

Tags: arraylist

This method needs to sort and array and I am close with the following code but what it does is puts the list forwards to backwards i.e. if the list was "5, 4, 3" this would change it to "3, 4, 5". This is because after the if statement completes it goes back to the for and once it is finished the for it sets lowest back to 1000. How do I make it not set it back to 1000 each time?

public void sortList()
    {

```
    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
    {
        int lowest = 1000;
        if(myList.get(i)<lowest)
        {
            myList.add(0, myList.get(i));
            myList.remove(i+1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
public void sortList() {

    int lowest = 1000;
    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
    {

        if(myList.get(i)<lowest)
        {
            myList.add(0, myList.get(i));
            myList.remove(i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply declare lowest outside of the loop, and update it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

With the example you gave, I would move the 'lowest' declaration out of the for loop, like so:

```
int lowest = 1000;
for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
{
    if(myList.get(i)<lowest)
    {
        myList.add(0, myList.get(i));
        myList.remove(i+1);
    }
}
```

That way it's not reset to 1000 with each for loop. You can then update it within the loop as needed as you would any other numeric variable.